# how to use aes_string for groups in ggplot2 inside a function when making boxplot

Tags: r, string, ggplot2

new to ggplot2, I've scoured the web but still couldn't figure this out. 
I understand how to plot a boxplot in ggplot2, my problem is that I can't pass along the variable I use for groups when it is inside a function.

so, normally (i.e. NOT inside a function), I would write this:

```
ggplot(myData, aes(factor(Variable1), Variable2)) +
    geom_boxplot(fill="grey", colour="black")+
    labs(title = "Variable1 vs. Variable2" ) +
    labs (x = "variable1", y = "Variable2")
```

Where myData is my data frame
Variable 1 is a 2 level factor variable
Variable 2 is a continuous variable
I want to make boxplots of Variable 1 by its 2 levels/groups
and this works fine, 
but as soon as I write this inside a function I couldn't get it to work.

my attempt in writing the function:

```
myfunction = function (data, Variable1) {
    ggplot(data=myData, aes_string(factor("Variable1"), "Variable2"))+
    geom_boxplot(fill="grey", colour="black")+
    labs(title = paste("Variable1 vs. Variable2" )) +
    labs (x = "variable1", y = "Variable2")
}
```

this only gives me a single boxplot(instead of 2), as if it never understood the factor(Variable1) command (and did a single boxplot of the entire Variable 2, rather than separate them by Variable 1 level first, then boxplot them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aes_string evaluates the entire string, so if you do `sprintf("factor(%s)",Variable1)` you get the desired result. As a further remark: your function has a data-argument, but inside the plotting you use `myData`. I have also edited the x-lab and title, so that you can pass 'Variable3' and get proper labels.

With some example data:

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(Variable2=rnorm(100),Variable1=c(0,1),Variable3=sample(0:1,100,T))

myfunction = function (data, Variable1) {
  ggplot(data=data, aes_string(sprintf("factor(%s)",Variable1), "Variable2"))+
    geom_boxplot(fill="grey", colour="black")+
    labs(title = sprintf("%s and Variable2", Variable1)) +
    labs (x = Variable1, y = "Variable2")
}

p1 <- myfunction(dat,"Variable1")
p2 <- myfunction(dat,"Variable3")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! this works perfectly. I didn't know of sprintf(), very handy! and you are right, I made a mistake with the myData inside the function. Thank you!